# How to solve an error `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.` with show()

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I'm currently developing an application using android-studio with Kotlin.

I want to use a bottom sheet, but when I call the `show()` method I have an error and I have no idea how to solve it...

When I hover a cursor on the `show()` I have this error message.

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

・show(FragmentManager!, String!) defined in com sample.myprojectname.BottomSheetFragment
・show(FragmentTransaction!, String!) defined in com sample.myprojectname.BottomSheetFragment
```

How can I solve this error?

---

Here are the codes:

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.bottomsheetvalue"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.sample.bottomsheetvalue

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val bottomSheet = BottomSheet()
            bottomSheet.show(supportFragmentManager,"navigation_bottom_sheet")
                      //↑ I have the error here
        }

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

BottomSheet.kt

```
package com.sample.bottomsheetvalue
    
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
    
    class BottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment()
    
    {
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false)
            return view
        }
}
```

fragment_bottom_sheet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".BottomSheet">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

---

Android Studio : 3.3.2

Comment: The Material Components library needs androidx classes. You're using the old support library. You'll need to [migrate your project to androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: @Mike M., Now it works well, thank you for your support!!